# Bazel's StrictJavaDepsPlugin and AutoValue_StrictJavaDepsPlugin_SjdDiagnostic

Tags: bazel

In my IDE, `https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/12987e858cca0e517f429fec2340ef69a2b9260a/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/analysis/BlazeVersionInfo.java` have these symbol: `AutoValue_StrictJavaDepsPlugin_SjdDiagnostic` and Kinds.Kind that are not defined anywhere in bazel ...
Am I missing something ? How can Bazel compile with such ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoValues are generated by an annotation processor at compile time, so there are no source files for these classes.

I can't find `Kinds.Kind`, could you update your question explaining what that is or where it's used?

Comment: Thanks Laszlo, line 261 in https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/b5630397cf440e7bee3a3b836fa546a537602b1d/src/java_tools/buildjar/java/com/google/devtools/build/buildjar/javac/plugins/dependency/StrictJavaDepsPlugin.java


      if (sym == null || sym.kind != Kinds.Kind.TYP) {
        return;
      }

Comment: Ah for the @AutoValue I installed https://github.com/afcastano/AutoValuePlugin/blob/master/README.md, that solved it, for the Kinds.Kind still no idea...

Comment: Another weird thing is com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner, has no visitPackageDef() to be overriden... 
`private static class CheckingTreeScanner extends TreeScanner {... @Override public void visitPackageDef ...}`

Comment: `Kinds` is imported as [`com.sun.tools.javac.code.Kinds`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/b5630397cf440e7bee3a3b836fa546a537602b1d/src/java_tools/buildjar/java/com/google/devtools/build/buildjar/javac/plugins/dependency/StrictJavaDepsPlugin.java#L29), so it's some JavaC class. I found this on Google (only for Java 7 unfortunately): http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Type.html

Comment: com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner#visitPackageDef is in JDK 9 I think... https://github.com/FauxFaux/jdk9-langtools/blob/master/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/tree/TreeScanner.java